# Ubuntu with Netatalk and Samba TimeMachine can't connect

Tags: samba, ubuntu-10.04, time-machine, netatalk

I installed netatalk on my Ubuntu Server a few weeks ago and configured it so that I could use Timemachine from my mac to backup on a server instead of a external hard drive.

It worked really good until yesterday when I installed Samba to be able to share certain folders on my server to my mac.

Now I receive an error msg:

```
There are no shares available or you are not allowed to access them on the server. Please contact your system administrator to resolve the problem.
```

From what I understand is that the problem is on the server and not on my mac. I have tried to restart the computer and without adding any of the folders Samba is sharing adding the timemachine "afp://...@...".

Is there a problem running them both at the same time, do I need to configure samba so that it doesn't reject afp?

I'm pretty new at this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get more info on the issue with the debug log of `afpd` (Apple Filing Protocol daemon, part of netatalk package). To obtain it, add the following to configuration line in `afpd.conf` (it's usually located at the bottom of the file):

```
-setuplog "default log_debug /var/log/afpd.log"
```

E.g., my config line looks like this:

```
- -tcp -noddp -mimicmodel TimeCapsule6,106 -uamlist uams_dhx2.so -setuplog "default log_debug /var/log/afpd.log"
```

After that, restart `netatalk` service and try to connect to your server from a mac. The `/var/log/afpd.log` now contain a lot of useful info for resolving the issue. Also, please provide contents of your `afpd.conf` and `AppleVolumes.default` (without commented lines, cause there are a lot of it). Mentioned files located in `/etc/netatalk`, at least in Archlinux.